# TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 6 positional arguments but 7 were given

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, oop, python-multithreading

I am using multithreading concept in my script. But I am getting the above error while running the script. I used the same code in python 2.7 and it worked fine but in python 3.6 it is giving me error. Could you please help me how to solve this?

Code Which I am using-

```
class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs={}, Verbose=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, Verbose)
        self._return = None
    def run(self):
        if self._Thread__target is not None:
            self._return = self._Thread__target(*self._Thread__args,
                                                **self._Thread__kwargs)
    def join(self):
        Thread.join(self)
        return self._return
```

May be syntax is different in python 3.6 Please help me to solve this error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/HTA/Scripts/Python/HTA_Consump_Layer_Procs.py", line 588, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/HTA/Scripts/Python/HTA_Consump_Layer_Procs.py", line 585, in main
    parallel_Execution()
  File "/app/HTA/Scripts/Python/HTA_Consump_Layer_Procs.py", line 395, in parallel_Execution
    p2 = ThreadWithReturnValue(target = partial(parallel_temp2, unique_exec_seq, df ))
  File "/app/HTA/Scripts/Python/HTA_Consump_Layer_Procs.py", line 365, in __init__
    Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, Verbose)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 6 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

Comment: @toRex Getting this error - AttributeError: 'ThreadWithReturnValue' object has no attribute '_Thread__target'

Comment: @toRex I did this -

class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, *, daemon=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon=daemon)
        self._return = None
    def run(self):
        if self._Thread__target is not None:
            self._return = self._Thread__target(*self._Thread__args,
                                                **self._Thread__kwargs)
    def join(self):
        Thread.join(self)
        return self._return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did a trial of ignoring Verbose in `Thread.__init__()` Then it works fine to my end. Find my demo code and output. Prior `Python<3` used `Verbose` in Thread but after `3.x+` Verbose is ignored.

```
from threading import Thread

def foo(bar):
    print('hello {0}'.format(bar))
    return "foo"

class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, Verbose=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs)
        self._return = None

    def run(self):
        if self._target is not None:
            self._return = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

    def join(self, *args):
        Thread.join(self, *args)
        return self._return


twrv = ThreadWithReturnValue(target=foo, args=('world!',))
twrv.start()
print(twrv.join())

# Output
# hello world!
# foo
```

Comment: class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs={}, Verbose=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs)
        self._return = None
    def run(self):
        if self._Thread__target is not None:
            self._return = self._Thread__target(*self._Thread__args,
                                                **self._Thread__kwargs)
    def join(self, *args):
        Thread.join(self, *args)
        return self._return

Comment: I did the above one but getting the error.

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: i am using python 3.6

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/app/HTA/Scripts/Python/HTA_Consump_Layer_Procs.py", line 368, in run
    if self._Thread__target is not None:
AttributeError: 'ThreadWithReturnValue' object has no attribute '_Thread__target'

Comment: Copy the whole code in your IDE and run then see what is happening.

Comment: Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 13 2020, 07:46:32)